# How to view Rails test output in the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I could have sworn there was a way to see Rails test output in your browser back in the early 2.x days similar to what Jasmine does for Javascript.

Am I crazy or does this exist? If so, is it a gem? How can I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you mean by this -- since you have to run Rails tests on the commandline, how/why would they wind up in your browser?

That said, maybe you're thinking of code coverage reports? Those generate HTML files that show the percentage of code for each file that is tested, and look something like this:

[image]

[image]

Those screenshots are both from [simplecov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov), the de-facto Ruby test coverage library.

Comment: That's pretty much it, yeah - I'm assuming those rcov reports are generated after `rake test` if you have the rcov gem included with your Rails app?

Comment: Pretty much, except this is simplecov, not rcov. Check out [the documentation on Github](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov) -- it tells you how to go about generating coverage reports, make sure they aren't added to your git repository accidentally, and so on.